# Converting a project using Drush in localhost

Tags: 7, drush, upgrading

I have a D6 project in my localhost

i.e   `C:\wamp\www\ProjectName_6`

I need to migrate the above mentioned project to D7 in the same directory using drush.

Should be like this `C:\wamp\www\ProjectName_7`

I am using Drush Version 5.7 which is located in the following path

`C:\Documents and Settings\All Users\Application Data\Drush\`

Could anyone kindly provide a **step-by-step guide to complete this process** or any **good links which is suitable for new bie**...

I googled a lot. But can't find any good article... (My search keywords may be wrong... )

Comment: Generally speaking, a Drupal 6 project cannot be converted to a Drupal 7 project with Drush; it could require rewriting code, and Drush doesn't do that. Also, Drupal 6 and Drupal 7 cannot co-exist in the same directory. Why would you need a Drupal 6 module in the same directory a Drupal 7 module is?

Comment: That's not a major requirement (D6 and D7 in same directory). My idea is to check the project in my local machine... My major criteria is to upgrade the project from D6 to D7.. I have found some articles that using Drush is the best way to do so... that's why I am trying to do with drush. Example Article : https://www.acquia.com/blog/use-drush-upgrade-drupal-6-drupal-7 Correct me If I am wrong.... I am ready to adopt if there any other good way to do the same... I have check with Drush Site Upgrade Module. But only version 7 is there... Any ideas will be thankful...

Comment: The article you are referring is talking of modules that are hosted on Drupal.org. If you are talking of a module you are developed, or that is not hosted on Drupal.org, then what said in that article doesn't apply for you.

Comment: Yes... my project contains just one custom module. That's why I am trying to do with drush... Could you kindly provide the step-by-step guide to complete this process.. Which will be grateful and thankful...

Comment: You cannot do that for a custom module, with Drush.

Comment: Yes.. I know that... I will rewrite my custom moudles manually... To be clear kindly consider that in my project I am having modules that are hosted on Drupal.org. Now could you guide me how to do the upgradtion process using drush... Hope this makes sense...

Comment: Did you read https://www.acquia.com/blog/use-drush-upgrade-drupal-6-drupal-7? Can you describe what you didn't understand in that article?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/6205/discussion-between-fero-and-kiamlaluno)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Drush Site Upgrade 7.x-2.x is for upgrading FROM Drupal 6 sites TO Drupal 7 sites.  I know that the version numbering is a bit confusing, but it is based on the fact that the Current version of Drush is 7.x-5.x.  This version of Drush supports both Drupal 6 and Drupal 7, but is versioned 7.x to match the most recent stable version of Drupal supported.  Similarly, Drush Site Upgrade is versioned 7.x to match the version of Drush that it works with.  I added a sentence to the Drush Site Upgrade homepage to clarify that it is for D6 -> D7 upgrades; the README.txt already explains this.

As for a step-by-step guide to using Drush Site Upgrade, please understand that the Drush Site Upgrade command itself **is** a step-by-step guide to upgrading your Drupal site.  This command will print out an explanation of what it is about to do at every step, and then prompt you before taking action.  Run with the --always-prompt flag when you're first getting started to insure that absolutely everything will be prompted.  If there is a step that is not applicable, or does not work right for your environment, you can tell Drush sup to skip the step, you can do the operation(s) you need to by hand, and Drush sup can continue the upgrade process on the next step.  If something goes horribly wrong, you can always start over from the beginning and try again.

As you inferred, Drush Site Upgrade will not actually upgrade the code of your custom modules to D7.  For help with that, please see http://upgrade.boombatower.com/.